# Compile with older cmake version

Tags: macos, cmake, version

I have the following problem using my Mac Os X 64bit: I've installed the latest cmake version (3.6.1) on my computer. Now I have to compile a code which requires cmake version between 2.8.4 and 2.8.9. I've tried to compile it with my 3.6.1 cmake version but it gives me errors. How can I install and run an older cmake version just to compile this code?

Thank you very much

Comment: `How can I install and run an older cmake version just to compile this code?` - Have you check [Download](https://cmake.org/download/) page for CMake?

Comment: Yes, I have, but I didn't find any information regarding this issue. That's why I'm asking it.

Comment: Download page refers to https://cmake.org/files, where you can find CMake of suitable version for your PC (Mac OS files have `Darwin` suffix). Just download corresponded file and follow standard procedure for installing programs on your platform. Actually, even latest versions of CMake have compatibility mode: if the code issues command `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)`, then it is processed with rules similar to ones for given version. What errors are generated by CMake for your code? It could be problems with the code, not a CMake version issues.

Comment: The error it throws out:CMake Error at src/cmake/TargetTools.cmake:2633 (message): Target doxyfilter: Expected two elements in SOURCES list! Have you accidentally modified this read-only property or is your (newer) CMake version not compatible with BASIS?
See also "/Users/Solbia/Downloads/dramms-1.4.2-source/build/bundle/src/BASIS-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make[2]: *** [bundle/src/BASIS-stamp/BASIS-configure] Error 1
This is a problem with cmake version. If I install the 2.8.4 version of cmake, how can I run the compiler with that version and not the 3.6.1?

Comment: Hmm, yes, this actually looks like CMake version incopatibility. `If I install the 2.8.4 version of cmake, how can I run the compiler with that version and not the 3.6.` - CMake and compiler are unrelated packages. Any CMake installation looks at well-known places for find compiler.

Comment: How do you call your downloaded version? Have you tried cmake --version with the downloaded one? What's the output?